# Why is Matt lying about not killing anybody?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

In Season 1 Episode 10 Nelson asks "have you killed anyone before?". Matt said no.

But Matt actually killed Nobu!

Why is he lying?

Answer (score 12):

> Nelson asks "did you killed anyone before?"

### That's not quite what Foggy asks.

The conversation goes something like.

> **Foggy** Are you telling me the truth?
>
> **Matt** I didn't kill him, Foggy. (referring to the murdered junkie)
>
> **Foggy** So, you've never,  you've never gone that far?
>
> **Matt** No. But I.. I wanted to after Elena after everything Fisk had done. I... I went to a warehouse I thought he'd be at. I went to kill him.
>
> **Foggy**: It's not enough playing judge and jury? You gotta add **executioner** to the list?

So Foggy isn't actually asking if he's "killed before" but rather has he **murdered** someone while he's acting like a vigilante.

Nobu "dies", sure, but it was an act of **self-defence** not murder or an execution.

The emphasis isn't on "never"...it's on **"that far".** As far as murder.

It's a fine distinction, perhaps, but still the truth.

Comment: thanks for your answer. "So you've **NEVER** gone that far?" What it means??

Comment: Nice answer, can't relate with downvote and I do remember that conversation from my memory too.

Comment: @AravindhGopi: Foggy and Matt were discussing the morality of someone who is willing to **murder**. While Nobu did die, Matt did not plan to murder him. This difference doesn't change the fact of Nobu's death, but it does mean that Matt's actions were not morally reprehensible. Foggy and Matt are talking about something that is morally reprehensible, so Nobu's death is not relevant to the discussion.